# How can I use nine-point circle to solve this concyclic problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, triangle-centres

I saw this problem on the Discord Math channel.

> *H* is the orthocenter of △*ABC*. *D*, *E* and *F* are the foot of the altitudes of △*ABC* passing through *A*, *B* and *C* respectively.  Lines *EF* and *BC* intersect at *R*.  The line parallel to *EF* passing through *D* intersects *AB* and *AC* at *P* and *Q* respectively.  *M* is the midpoint of *BC*.  Prove that *M*, *P*, *Q* and *R* are concyclic.

[image: geometric problem]

Someone said that this can be proved using the nine-point circle, but I tried hard drawing figures to see things like ∠*FEM* = ∠*BDF* = ∠*BAC*.  I also know that *BM* = *CM* = *EM* = *FM*.  However, when *P* and *M* come together, I find the angle calculations hard because *M* is defined by a side length, and *P* is defined by an angle.  I can't see a way without using trigonometry functions.

I've derived on my own the following basic result that the orthic triangle △*DEF* admits *H* as its incenter.  I've used the result (1) in the previous paragraph.

[image]

I showed this by the converse of the intersecting chords theorem instead of nine-point circle.  I've chosen this approach for two reasons:

1. I've got lost in the figures while calculating angles.
2. *M* is defined by a side length, so it'll be easier to calculate side lengths.

*MD* ⋅ *DR* = (0.5 *BC* − *CD*) (*DC* + *CR*)      ⋯⋯ ①

We calculate *CR* to eliminate *R* from this product.  I used Ceva's Theorem and Menelaus's Theorem to see that |*BR* : *RC*| = *BD* : *DC*.  This gives

*RC* : *CB* = *RC* : |*BR* − *RC*| = *DC* : (*BD* − *DC*) = *CD* : (*BC* − 2*CD*)
*CR* = *BC* ⋅ *CD* / (*BC* − 2*CD*)      ⋯⋯ ②

Substitute ② into ①:

*MD* ⋅ *DR*
= (0.5 *BC* − *CD*) (*DC* + *CR*)
= 0.5 (*BC* − 2*CD*) [1 + *BC* / (*BC* − 2*CD*)] *CD*
= 0.5 [(*BC* − 2*CD*) + *BC*] *CD*
= (*BC* − *CD*) *CD*
= *BD* ⋅ *CD*      ⋯⋯ ③

Observe that *B*, *Q*, *C* and *P* are concyclic.

| observation | *reason* |
| --- | --- |
| ∠*CQD* = ∠*AEF* | *corr*. ∠*s*, *EF* // *PQ* |
| ∠*AEF* = ∠*ABC* | *result* (1) *in above screenshot* |
| ∴ ∠*CQD* = ∠*DBP* |  |
| i.e. *B*, *Q*, *C* and *P* are concyclic. | *converse of* ∠*s in same seg*. |
| *BD* ⋅ *DC* = *PD* ⋅ *DQ* | *chord thm*. |
| *MD* ⋅ *DR* = *BD* ⋅ *DC* | ③ |
| ∴ *MD* ⋅ *DR* = *PD* ⋅ *DQ* |  |
| i.e. *M*, *P*, *Q* and *R* are concyclic. | *converse of chord thm*. |

*Q.E.D.*

Comment: The Euler circle is not really helpful in the given situation, since $R$ is not "playing a game" on the same stage (in an obvious manner).

Comment: The [original question on Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjiIv.png) really mentions "nine-point circle".  I'm posting the screenshot as a message to provide a bit more context without modifying the question body.  I've blurred the user names and the avatars to avoid putting others into display.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to proceed explicitly using similarities of triangles and the power of a point w.r.t. a circle. By symmetry, we may and do suppose that $\hat C$ is bigger than $\hat B$. Well, *strictly* bigger, else there is no $R$. The solution lives then in the following picture:

[image: math stackexchange power of point application]

Here,
$
\widehat{BPQ} =
\widehat{BFE} = 180^\circ-\hat C=
\widehat{BCQ}
$, so $BPCQ$ cyclic, giving for the power of $D$ w.r.t. the circle $\odot(BPCQ)$
$$
\tag{$1$}
DP\cdot DQ=DB\cdot DC\ .
$$
(We want to compute $DM\cdot DR$ and show it is equal to the above. For this, $DR$ is re-expressed using similarities to "get closer" to lengths simpler related to $\Delta ABC$.)

Let $N\in AB$ be the point making $\Delta NBC$ isosceles. Then the two green angles in the pictures are congruent, same measure $\hat C-\hat B$, leading to $\Delta DRE\sim\Delta ACN$, so
$$
\tag{$2$}
\frac{DR}{AC}
=
\frac{DE}{AN}
=
\frac{\displaystyle\frac{DE}{AB}}{\displaystyle\frac{AN}{AB}}
=
\frac{\displaystyle\frac{DC}{AC}}{\displaystyle\frac{DM}{DB}}
=
\frac{DB\cdot DC}{AC\cdot DM}
\ .
$$
Simplifying with $AC$, we get
$$
\tag{$3$}
DM\cdot DR=DB\cdot DC\ .
$$
From $(1)$ and $(3)$ we get $DM\cdot DR=DP\cdot DQ$, so $MRPQ$ cyclic.

$\square$

Comment: This is in essence the same way as in the compact solution of Jack D'Aurizio, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio - same first step to use $BCPQ$ cyclic as also mentioned by OP, same second step, some explicit third step replaces the use of a cross ratio argument.

Comment: I appreciate your constructive responsive.  It takes me some time to understand that you've made use of the assumption in the beginner for the existence of such point *N*., and that the transition in the middle of equation ② is due to the observation that  Δ*NBM* ∼ Δ*ABD*.  Sorry I am not able to see how his 3rd step would be simple for the moment, but I'd be glad to read if there's an explanation from someone else.

Comment: The point $N$ exists for a simple reason, intersect the side bisector of $BC$ with the line $AB$. From the assumption $\hat B<\hat C$ the point $N$ is in the interior of the segment $AB$. From the relation $(3)$ use the power of a point properties to conclude. (The reciprocals more exactly.) But explicitly, directly, without using this, from $(3)$ and $(1)$ we get$$\frac{DM}{DQ}=\frac{DP}{DR}\ ,$$and from $\widehat{MDP}=\widehat{QDR}$ we get $\Delta MDP\sim\Delta QDR$, so $\widehat{MPQ}=\widehat{MPD}=\widehat{DRQ}=\widehat{MRQ}$, so $PMQR$ cyclic.

Comment: thx for further explanation.  i'm ok with power of circle.  i made a typo when i was typing my previous message:  i didn't see how another solution would be significantly "shorter".
i wanted to say "short" instead of "simple".  my mind blocked me.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter solution:

- $B,P,C,Q$ are concyclic, since $APQ$ is similar to $AFE$, which is similar to $ACB$
- By the chords theorem $BD\cdot DC= PD\cdot DQ$, hence it is enough to show that $RD\cdot DM = BD\cdot DC$...
- ... which is fairly simple by [cross ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio), for instance.

Comment: thx for response but how can cross ratios helps in this problem?  i tried writing stuff like $$(B,M;D,C) = \frac{BD \cdot MC}{MD \cdot BC} = \frac{BD}{MD} \cdot \frac12.$$  maybe i need one of the four points to be $\infty$?